# Changing hyperlink image to a second image while resizing and repositioning second image on hover over whilst leaving the first image in place

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an image to swap out for another image and simultaneously change the position and sizing on the screen 
for the second image when the first is hovered over - the image is also an anchor tag hyperlink when clicked on ...

This is the site I am working on : http://thefestivalgame.co.uk/

I want to swap out the 'Rollaz&Movas' image (top right) with the dice image that does appear when hovered over, but I also want to 
change the hovered dice images' position without altering the size/position of the 'Rollaz&Movas' image when hovering?

This is the code I already have that 'sort of' works but doesn't allow me to target the second (dice) image for resize and 
re-position?

This is my HTML

```css
.roll { transition: all .9s ease-in-out; }

.roll:hover { transform: scale(1.2); }
```

```html
<a href="images/dicepage.png" title="#Rollaz&Movaz!" target="_blank"><img class="roll" src="images/rollaz.png" alt="The Festival game" style="width:25%; height:auto; position: absolute ;
 float:left;
 left: 74%;
 top: 1%;"
 onmouseover="this.src='images/rolova.png'"
        onmouseout="this.src='images/rollaz.png'"/></a>
```

I can't figure out how to target the second hovered 'dice' image to move/resize it without the same thing happening to the 
unhovered image which needs to stay where it is - the position of the dice image is not crucail as I have not decided where 
to have it appear yet, I would just like to know how to move it, if that is possible?

All the scaling is done with %-age values - pixel size is no good.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JavaScript to change the image do everything in CSS.

```
<a href="images/dicepage.png" title="#Rollaz&Movaz!" target="_blank" id="link-image"></a>   

#link-image { 
    background: url(images/rollaz.png) left top; 
    width: [the image width];
    height: [the image height];
}
#link-image:hover {  
    background: url(images/rolova.png) left top; 
    width: [the image width]; 
    height: [the image height];
}
```

Comment: No, sorry, this solution doesn't work. All that happens is both the images, hovered over or not, vanish ...

Comment: Yeah, I did not give you the full working solution but only a hint at which way you should go.

Comment: Well, I didn't just copy/paste your solution because the image directory is ../ from your example, but, even when modified to the correct path it still does not work.